# Asymptotic runtime of list-to-tree function

Tags: haskell, time, complexity-theory, big-o

I have a `merge` function which takes time `O(log n)` to combine two trees into one, and a `listToTree` function which converts an initial list of elements to singleton trees and repeatedly calls `merge` on each successive pair of trees until only one tree remains.

Function signatures and relevant implementations are as follows:

```
merge :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a --// O(log n) where n is size of input trees
singleton :: a -> Tree a            --// O(1)
empty :: Tree a                     --// O(1)
listToTree :: [a] -> Tree a         --// Supposedly O(n)

listToTree = listToTreeR . (map singleton)

listToTreeR :: [Tree a] -> Tree a
listToTreeR []     = empty
listToTreeR (x:[]) = x
listToTreeR xs     = listToTreeR (mergePairs xs)

mergePairs :: [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
mergePairs []       = []
mergePairs (x:[])   = [x]
mergePairs (x:y:xs) = merge x y : mergePairs xs
```

This is a slightly simplified version of exercise 3.3 in Purely Functional Data Structures by Chris Okasaki.

According to the exercise, I shall now show that `listToTree` takes `O(n)` time.  Which I can't. :-(

There are trivially `ceil(log n)` recursive calls to `listToTreeR`, meaning `ceil(log n)` calls to `mergePairs`.

The running time of `mergePairs` is dependent on the length of the list, and the sizes of the trees.  The length of the list is `2^h-1`, and the sizes of the trees are `log(n/(2^h))`, where `h=log n` is the first recursive step, and `h=1` is the last recursive step.  Each call to `mergePairs` thus takes time `(2^h-1) * log(n/(2^h))`

I'm having trouble taking this analysis any further.  Can anyone give me a hint in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost there. You already know the expression is

> [image]

so the only problem is to evaluate this sum. Using log(AB) = log A + log B and log 2<sup>N</sup> = N we have

> [image]

[With help of calculators](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+2%5eh+%28m+-+h%29+from+h%3D1+to+m), we can find that X = O(2<sup>m</sup>) = O(n), which is expected.

(If you want to compute this yourself, search for "Geometric series", or approximate the sum using an integral.)